# Sum of day/month/year

Tags: python, list, loops, date, variable-assignment

I have to write a program where I find how many days of the year equal 7.
Example:
1/3/21 = 1+3+2+1 = 7.

My first idea was to create a list for the days, and then somehow loop it through for each month (and save the dates in a new list), but I'm not sure that's the best way.

No need for any difficult code, this is a beginner assignment.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @aida_m, welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please elaborate more your questions, putting some attempts you have made and errors you have found when trying them?

Comment: As a beginner you don't need the best way. Play around a bit and use what works. If you have a specific issue you can ask here with your code.

Comment: @MichaelButscher yes, I have tried a little but am struggling with the structure - what loops I should use and things like that. :D

Comment: A for-loop for the month and a nested for-loop in it for the days. In this inner loop check the date for the condition and increment a counter if it is met.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you so much! I'll give it a try, and come back if I'm still having problems!